# What is the simplest and quickest way to export your SQL Server table columns and their types to a BigQuery table?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table contains 120 columns in SQL Server and I have to replicate the same column names and their types in BigQuery.

Creating a table column with its datatype one by one for the above in Bigquery takes a lot of time. Is there a quicker way to create it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for :

[generate DDL script from SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557619/generate-ddl-script-from-sql-server-database)

```
DECLARE @C VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'EXEC [DBO].[SP_GETDDL] '''+NAME+'''' FROM SYS.TABLES
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @C
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
EXEC (@C)
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @C
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate script ..

1. Right click on your database
2. goto Generate Script
3. Select Db objects Like (Tables, Stored procedures) which you want to generate script of!
4. Click "Next Button"
5. Select any option for having query like "new Query Editor" or Save File to clipboard ..

Answer (score 0):

You can write an sql script that gets the table schema from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. COLUMNS view in the form of BigQuery JSON schema format :

```
[
 {
   "description": "[DESCRIPTION]",
   "name": "[NAME]",
   "type": "[TYPE]",
   "mode": "[MODE]"
 },
 {
   "description": "[DESCRIPTION]",
   "name": "[NAME]",
   "type": "[TYPE]",
   "mode": "[MODE]"
 }
]
```

and then simply use this JSON to create the table in BigQuery.

but first you need to map the datatypes between SQL Server and BigQuery
for example varchar in sql server is equivalent to STRING in bigquery

you can use the json to create the table using CLI, Python or even Google cloud console. ([Specifying a schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas) )

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be exporting a sample data of your table (could be 10 rows or less with headers and without nulls) as CSV from your SQL Server, then load this file into Bigquery with Auto Schema detection.

If after this, you want to get the Bigquery Schema to create another table or use it for another propose, you could get the schema by using this command.

```
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson dataset.table > schema.json
```